# Spring RestController ignore XmlElement annotation in Wrapper Class

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I'm using Spring 4.x and I have following RestController method which should return list of all flights

```
@RequestMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public FlightWrapper returnAllFlights() {
    List<FlightDto> flights = data.findAll();

    return new FlightWrapper(flights);
}
```

FlightWrapper class looks like this (rootElement = flight**s** element = flight):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "flights")
public class FlightWrapper {

    private List<FlightDto> flights;

    public FlightWrapper() {}

    public FlightWrapper(List<FlightDto> flights) {
        this.flights = flights;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "flight")
    public List<FlightDto> getFlights() {
        return flights;
    }

    public void setFlights(List<FlightDto> flights) {
        this.flights = flights;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I call returnAllFlights() it will return xml in this format:

```
<FlightWrapper>
    <flights>
        <flights>
            ....
        </flights>
        <flights>
            ....
        </flights>
    </flights>
</FlightWrapper>
```

I expected that single flight should have tag **flight** and whole list of flights should be **flights** however as you can see items in list have the same tag as list itself.

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Clean and Rebuild your code, it is practically almost the same than a previous project I had. Could you add the OXM or `Marshaller` technology configuration?. Your controller is `@RestController`?

Comment: Yes my controller is @RestController I am using spring boot 1.4.1. For xml support I just added dependency to maven jackson-dataformat-xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According with your comments since you are using `jackson-dataformat-xml` module the JAXB annotations now are ignored. You must update your class to use these annotations.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="flights")
public class FlightWrapper {

    private List<FlightDto> flights;

    public FlightWrapper() {}

    public FlightWrapper(List<FlightDto> flights) {
        this.flights = flights;
    }

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="flight")        
    public List<FlightDto> getFlights() {
        return flights;
    }

    public void setFlights(List<FlightDto> flights) {
        this.flights = flights;
    }
}
```

I had the same problem than you but through `Spring Framework`, not through `Spring Boot`. But that behaviour happens when the `jackson-dataformat-xml` module is added into the classpath. It according with my experience.